# FCM HTTP v1 API Deep Link Handling

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm migrating away from the [Legacy FCM API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), and the way I triggered deep links in the legacy notification was like this:

```json
{
    "to": "/topics/MY_TOPIC"
    "notification": {
        "title": "My Title",
        "text": "My Text",
        "link": "https://www.example.com/deeplink/valid-link"
    },
    "data": {
        "a": "content",
        "p": 0,
        "t": "My Title",
        "_ab": "true",
        "uri": "https://www.example.com/deeplink/valid-link",
    },
}
```

When the device received the previous notification in the background and tapped the notification it resulted in the App handling the deep link correctly.

I cannot figure out how to do it in the new API:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send

I'm able to receive the notification/message, which looks like this:

```json
{
    "message": {
        "topic": "MY_TOPIC",
        "data": {
            "a": "content",
            "p": "0",
            "t": "My Title",
            "_ab": "true",
            "uri": "https://www.example.com/deeplink/valid-link"
        },
        "notification": {
            "title": "My Title",
            "body": "My Body",
            "image": "https://images.example.com/50x50.png"
        },
        "android": {
            "data": {
                "uri": "https://www.example.com/deeplink/valid-link"
            },
            "notification": {
                "click_action": "https://www.example.com/deeplink/valid-link"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to trigger the deep link with add and see the following log:

```
START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.example.com/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.exampleapp cmp=com.exampleapp/.ui.MainActivity} from uid 2000
```

However when I try the following:

```
"click_action": "android.intent.action.VIEW"
```

The information is defined as "extras":

```
START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x14000000 pkg=com.exampleapp (has extras)} from uid 10146
```

What's the right way to achieve the same in the new API? I've scoured the docs to no avail, thinking I'm missing something obvious.

Any help is appreciated, many thanks in advance?